# Getting "Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string"

Tags: php

First off, I'm *very* new to PHP and my English sometimes isn't that great, so I already apologize for the guesswork you guys may have to do.

The error I get is:

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string"

The code I have is:

```
mysql_connect("nope.com","nope","nope") or die ("Verbindung zur Datenbank konnte nicht hergestellt werden");
mysql_select_db("nope") or die ("Datenbank konnte nicht verbunden werden");
$nnamenow = $_SESSION['username']; 
echo(mysql_fetch_object(mysql_query("SELECT Name FROM USER WHERE Username LIKE '$nnamenow'")));
```

I have tried quite a number of different approaches with query-variables and so on, because until now rewriting code enough times in different ways always solved my issues.

Comment: `mysql_fetch_object` fetches a data record as an object, not as one string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try save query result to variable like

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT Name FROM USER WHERE Username LIKE '$nnamenow'");
```

then You can iterate by row

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row['Name'];
}
```

because this querty can return more than one row :)

Comment: Thanks for accept my answer, You can also vote up instead of write such comments :P Obviously You should also use mysqli, as anothers mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

That's error is very clear, You're trying to echoing an object.

```
$result = mysql_fetch_object(mysql_query("SELECT Name FROM USER WHERE Username LIKE '$nnamenow'"));
var_dump($result); // echo $result->Name;
```

**Waring:** [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: thank you, ill have a look at it. 
But honestly while the error is pretty clear do i still not understand it. The type of "data" im trying to echo from the database is varchar :/

Comment: @R3alr0ad While you only select a single field `Name` from the database, that is irrelevant to the mysql API. You could also `SELECT Name, Foo, Bar, Baz`. What would you expect the result of an `echo` to be then?

Comment: @deceze
I think i see what you mean. Im not echoing the data itself, im echoing the object it is. ( i hope my broken english will get across what i mean)
Thanks for the patience btw.
As i said, im still very new to PHP ( and coding in general )

Answer (score 1):

`mysql_fetch_object` returns an *object*. You then try to `echo` said object. You cannot `echo` an object, it will produce the error you see. You can only `echo` properties of said object.:

```
$obj = mysql_fetch_object(...);
echo $obj->Name;
```

You should also add a lot more error handling to your code and most of all stop using the `mysql_` functions; they're deprecated. Not everything has to be a one-liner.

Answer (score 0):

in PHP you can't echo an array or an object. Well, for objects, that's not entirely true, as you may implement the `__toString()` method, which lets you manage how to display an object whenever you need to convert it to a string.

In your case, your object is an instance of `StdClass`, so it won't work. You need to do a loop to display each field, or display each field separately (`$result->Name`, for example).